# Disable Font "Floaty" menu in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am using Powerpoint on Windows 10.  No matter where I click on text, I am plagued by a floating font menu that blocks my view of the content of the slide that I am composing.

I used the following registry change to disable the so-called "floaty" menu:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-disable-right-click-editing-font-menu/b4412b7a-b762-419e-b766-e32c4e1999dc

After rebooting, I am still getting the floaty menu.

**Is there a sure-fire way to get rid of "floaties"?**

**What might cause the cited process not to work?**

P.S. Unlike article cited above, I don't have a registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\Toolbars\PowerPoint`.  However, I do have `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Toolbars\PowerPoint`, which is where I created `DWORD` `AllowMenuFloaties` and set it to zero, as required.

Comment: None of the answers in that thread solved the problem, so we ar actually not sure if those work.

Comment: The person who answered the cited thread is a well known name that I recognize from past years.  If he posted it, I have confidence that it worked in some contexts.  It doesn't help me, though, with Office 2013 in Windows 10. Frankly, I don't know what the designer(s) was thinking, obstructing the very slide being composed without a means to disable it.